# Serialising / deserialising a Java HashMap in SimpleXML

Tags: java, hashmap, simple-framework

In a Java class of mine, I have an attribute:

`private HashMap<String, Integer> keywordFrequencies;`

And I need to serialise / deserialise objects of the class concerned.

Can SimpleXML represent this type of Java object? And what might the XML look like?

My XML is like this:

```
 <keywordFrequencies>
    <keyword key="Osborne">1</keyword>
    <keyword key="budget">3</keyword>
 </keywordFrequencies>
```

Code to deserialise at the moment is a generic method:

```
public static void printHashMap(HashMap<String, Integer> hm) {
    Set s = hm.entrySet();
    Iterator i = s.iterator();

    int j = 0;

    // Print the index.
    while(i.hasNext()) {
        Map.Entry m = (Map.Entry) i.next();
        System.out.println("No=" + (j + 1) + ", Key=" + m.getKey() + ", Freq=" + m.getValue());
        j++;
    }
}
```

The attribute in the Java class is:

```
@ElementMap(entry="keywordFrequencies", key="key", attribute=true, inline=true)
private HashMap<String, Integer> keywordFrequencies;
```

Where I am calling the method to print the hashmap as:

```
HashMap_Utils.printHashMap(requestOMDM.getKeywordFrequencies());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add

```
@ElementMap(entry="keywordFrequencies", key="key", attribute=true, inline=true)
private Map<String, Integer> keywordFrequencies;
```

http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#map

/edit, I have limited connection now but as I remember you can have...

You will have your bean that will be used to serialize to and from xml

```
@Root(name="root")
public class Example {

   @Element
   private String someProperty;

   @ElementMap(entry="keywordFrequencies", key="key", attribute=true, inline=true)
   private Map<String, Integer> keywordFrequencies;

   // getters and setters ommited
}

Serializer serializer = new Persister();
Example ex = new Example();
// set properties of ex here...
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
serializer.write(ex, baos); // you can put here a FileOutputStream("fileToWrite.xml") too
String content = new String(baos.getBytes(), "UTF-8");
System.out.println(content);
// and then to deserialize
Example retrievedFromXml = serializer.read(Example.class, content);
```

Does this helps ?

Comment: As far as I can see, there are 2 properties in the example, one is a map and one is a string. And yes, you can have many properties in your class that you use to serialize to/from xml

Comment: I'm having a problem with this. If this is my XML: `<keywordFrequencies>
  <keyword keywordText="Osborne">1</keyword>
  <keyword keywordText="budget">3</keyword>
       </keywordFrequencies>' then I should be able to read the elements in Java. But I get `Error java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "
  "/

Comment: Can you show your full bean and serialization/deserialization code ?

Comment: Question has been amended.

Comment: Oh, I see, you are not yet using simplexml. I have done something similar in the past, Give me some time today I will answer you. Your code is wrong because it does not have escaping in account unless you are sure your values can not conflict with valid xml structure

Comment: So the only thing you need is one method that does: String mapToXml(Map<String, String> map), and another that does: Map<String, String> xmlToMap(String map). Will this work for you ?

Comment: The hashmap is <String, Integer> but shouldn't the SimpleXML code work as you suggested earlier?

Comment: Yes it will work, but you need a bean holding the map, and I am not sure if the xml structure it will generate is the same as the one you have already. That is why I asked if the only thing you need is two methods, one fromXmlToMap and another fromMapToXml ? Or you need more complex structures that you will define in a bean with more properties ?

Comment: The XML code can vary. But I don't get the need for a bean containing the map. Don't I have that by virtue of the existing class I already have?

Comment: Ideally, two methods but the bean should have other attributes. Thanks.